# Авторизация VK с OAuth

Tags: oauth, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
$app_id = '***';
$app_secret = '***';
$my_url = "***/vk.php";
session_start();
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
if(empty($code)) {
    echo "FAIL";
} else {
    $token_url =  'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$code.'';
    var_dump(file_get_contents($token_url));
```

Выводит NULL. Может ли это быть проблема с сервером, или я где-то накосячил?

Comment: Про какую из авторизаций идёт речь? [Авторизация сайтов](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) или имитируете [мобильное приложение](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile)?

Comment: Спасибо всем, как оказалось - проблема в хостинге. Все настроено, но не работает, на локалхосте все отлично. Саппорт помочь не смог. Хостинг очень плохой видимо)

Answer (score 1):

ВК проверяет, что бы текущий домен был таким же как в конфигурации приложения.

Возможно, у Вас указан в настройках приложения некий домен, к примеру example.com, а разработку ведете на локальной машине, где доступ к сайту осуществляется по другому адресу (например example.local).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/5.0.3521/886; U; en) Presto/2.4.15");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$app_id.'&code='.$_REQUEST['code'].'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&redirect_uri='.$my_url);
    $answer = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0)
        die('curl error:' . curl_error($ch));
    $text_answer = print_r($answer, true);
    if (isset($answer['error_description']))
        echo '<p style="color:red;display:inline;">' . $answer['error'] . ': ' . $answer['error_description'] . '</p><br>';
    else

        {

          echo'<pre>';  print_r($answer); echo'</pre>';*/
        }

} else
    echo 'А где кодымодычмоды?';
```